Maven/Mapstruct generates wrong folder annotations under resource folder
I have a problem with my SpringBoot/Maven/Mapstruct project.
The project is a Spring-Boot 3.2.4 application with Maven 3.9.6 that I work on with IntelliJ IDEA (community - always updated)
I have a run configuration to run my SpringBoot App that builds the project before launching the app.
What happens is that when I run the application (and the build starts), Maven generates a folder called target.generated-sources.annotations.<my_package> , that is not under target/generated-sources, but it has created in one of the resource folder listed in the  tag of the build :

That's my pom.xml :
<project...>

<parent>
    ...
</parent>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>locale</id>
        <properties>
            <project.packaging.type>jar</project.packaging.type>
            <spring.profiles.active>locale</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.starter.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-info</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <additionalProperties>
                                    <encoding.source>UTF-8</encoding.source>
                                    <encoding.reporting>UTF-8</encoding.reporting>
                                    <java.version>${java.version}</java.version>
                                </additionalProperties>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    ... (Spring boot starters) ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.mapstruct.binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/application.yml</filter>
    </filters>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>../configurations/MTMsgFieldsRepository</directory>
            <targetPath>MTMsgFieldsRepository/</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>../configurations/SQLRepository</directory>
            <targetPath>SQLRepository/</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>../configurations/DAOSchema</directory> <--- The "strange" folder is created here!
            <targetPath>edcm-config/edop/</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>../configurations/environment/${environment-folder}/</directory>
            <targetPath>edcm-config/</targetPath>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>generic_config/</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>../configurations/environment/${environment-folder}/generic_config</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

I made some tries and I discovered something that I don't understand :

If I remove all the  folders, this folder is not created;
What (I think) causes this error is the mapStruct annotationProcessor. I tried to change the  with no success

If I launch a maven install, the Mappers are generated in target/generated-sources, but of course in the classpath there are duplicated mappers so the application won't start.
I cannot understand why this is happening. Is there anyone that already faced this error?
Many thanks
